# Treaty Question between Egypt and the USA?

Tags: usa, working-visas, taxes

In the [US-Egypt treaty](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/egypt.pdf), there is a condition that a person should come to the US for a period not expected to exceed 2 years. Is this decided based on the visa duration, the initial guaranteed contract, the project expected duration, the petition of the work visa, or what?

Here is the text:

> Where a resident of one of the Contracting States is invited by the
>   Government of the other Contracting State, a political subdivision, or
>   a local authority thereof, or by a university or other recognized
>   educational institution in that other Contracting State to come to
>   that other Contracting State for a period not expected to exceed 2
>   years for the purpose of teaching or engaging in research, or both, at
>   a university or other recognized educational institution and such
>   resident comes to that other Contracting State primarily for such
>   purpose, his income from personal services for teaching or research at
>   such university or educational institution shall be exempt from tax by
>   that other Contracting State for a period not exceeding 2 years from
>   the date of his arrival in that other Contracting State.

Comment: Yes, the USA-Egypt treaty, article 22 - http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/egypt.pdf

Comment: I did. I would like to know what you think. Thanks!